# Can anyone identify these tyranids from this description?

Tags: warhammer-40k, character-identification

In the audio book [Helion Rain](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8697260-helion-rain), some tyranid creatures are described but never actually identified.

I don't recognise them from their decsription,

> Two enormous tyranid creatures were hovering amongst the wreckage, about thirty metres from the Scout's current position. They were unlike anything Grayvus had seen before: **fat, bloated bodies crested by an array of chitinous plates and spines, each atop a long, curling tail that floated a metre above the ground. Their heads resembled that of the lictor, but bigger, their mouths ringed with squirming tendrils. Two small arms ended in vicious-looking talons. They were the colour of rotting flesh, pink and lurid, and towered at least three or four times the height of the Scout sergeant**.

Does anyone know what tyranids are being described here?

*I'm aware they could very well be unique tyranids to this story and not actually exist anywhere else*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [Malanthrope](http://www.forgeworld.co.uk/en-GB/Tyranid-Malanthrope):

[image]

It's not exactly bloated, but it's got the Liktor look, mouthfull of tendrils and two talons. Also it floats and is much bigger than a Scour Sergeant.

Comment: Yeah that definitely fits the bill!! Great work, there's a bounty on it's way to you once this question is eligible.